# Need best MVC 4 Web API Grid

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, mustache

Could any one please suggest the best MVC4 WEB API Grid ?

Right now we are using Mustache templates to display Data.
Current App: MVC 4 Web API, C#.Net, Visual Studio 2012, Mustache templates
Client wants Mustache templates to be replaced with nice grid with all the search and sorting features.

Answer (score 2):

[Datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net) provides a lot of functionality and is widely used.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using jqgrid - a lot of functionality and demos for mvc -

http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

Datatables, jqgrid, kendoUI etc.. they will in the long term cause you extreme frustration and unhappiness.

Best thing to do is really make data LOOK like a grid, you can have complete control and really understand what is going on and do sorting and paging etc..   Use Bootstrap for CSS and make ajax calls to Web Api.

Angular is really nice, but you can start without Angular.   I've been on 40 projects in which the 3 I mentioned caused a lot of headaches for many people including myself.